# Next.js loading every function on the page onload instead of waiting for when they're called normally

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

All my functions (imported or not) are loading onload (3 times) instead of when they're meant to be called. The main one that annoys me is onClick of a button and it opens a new page but instead when you go to the site, it just opens 3 new pages, and then since its the same page, it opens another 3 pages, and each of those 3 pages makes 3 new pages.

Button html:
`<button onClick={goBlank(getUrl())} className="ab">About:Blank</button>`

goBlank js:

```
function goBlank(url) {
  if(!url) {
    console.log("url not set " + url)
    return false;
  }
  console.log('test');
  var page = new ABC({
    "type": "blank",
  });
  page.setType("blank")
  page.setUrl(url)
  page.open()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass function reference to `onClick` method.

As This code will execute the function immediately.

```
<button onClick={goBlank(getUrl())} className="ab">About:Blank</button>
```

You can wrap your function in an anonymous function.

```
<button onClick={() => goBlank(getUrl())} className="ab">About:Blank</button>
```